# When is $N_G(H)/C_G(H)$ isomorphic to $\operatorname{Inn}(H)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I was wondering when is this true? Are there any nice conditions that $H$ has to fulfill?

Thank you!

Comment: Explain the notation. I'm guessing that $N$ means normalizer and $C$, centralizer?

Comment: @Jakobian Yes, and $H$ is a subgroup of G

Comment: [Consider the "$N/C$ Theorem".](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/814192/104041)

Comment: @Shaun I am aware of this theorem. However, it only tells us it is isomorphic to some subgroup of $Aut(H)$ not necessarily $Inn(H)$

Comment: You should state in an [edit] what you are and are not aware of.

Comment: You can always try to check, if $N(H)/C(H)$ *is* isomorphic to $\text{Inn}(H)$, what happens? This would probably be easier, and help you understand the problem more.

Comment: Would you count $N_G(H)=HC_G(H)$ being necessary/sufficient as an answer?

Comment: @runway44 Yes if you explain why it works :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put elementarily: if the image of $N_G(H)/C_G(H)\to\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ is in fact $\mathrm{Inn}(H)$ (which is the image of the composition $H/Z(H)\to N_G(H)/C_G(H)\to\mathrm{Aut}(G)$), then for every $g\in N_G(H)$ there exists an element $h\in H$ for which conjugation-by-$g$ matches conjugation-by-$h$ as automorphisms of $H$, in which case $h^{-1}g\in C_G(H)$. Therefore, $N_G(H)=HC_G(H)$. This is also clearly sufficient.

However, note in general it is possible for infinite groups to be isomorphic to their proper subgroups, so we can't rule out the image of $N_G(H)/C_G(H)$ within $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ strictly containing $\mathrm{Inn}(H)$ but still isomorphic to $\mathrm{Inn}(H)$.